# Attaching Custom Data to the blend file, scene, objects

Tags: python, blend-files

I see many examples that attach custom properties to objects eg.

```
bpy.types.Object.mytype = bpy.props.StringProperty()
```

What are the other useful places to put custom properties. In particular I want to store a global to the blend file itself?

```
 len(dir(bpy.types)) # -> 3282!
```

I see there is a type `BlendData`

Answer (score 3):

Only ID types, Bones and PoseBones support properties:

> Custom properties can be added to any subclass of an ID, Bone and PoseBone.

http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_70_release/bpy.props.html

The only type with just a single instance is `bpy.types.WindowManager`, but its properties aren't serialized to .blend.